# Mock and verify parameters from a class method in pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pytest-mock

I`m trying to use pytest-mock in my pytests.

How is it possible to mock a object method and verify the parameters of this object method in the same test?

In my example I want to mock the method "test_function" from the class Engine. And I want to check that the method "test_function" is called once with the expected parameters.

My current approach with monkeypatch and mocker.patch.object is complicated and it is not working. The mock_function is not called when the mocker.patch.object is active.

```
def test(monkeypatch, mocker):
  def mock_function(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
  
  monkeypatch.setattr(Engine, "test_function", mock_function)
  mock_object = mocker.patch.object(Engine, "test_function")
  
  service = Service(Engine())
  service.call_test_function("param", "param1", [["value"]])

  mock_object.assert_called_once_with("param", "param1", [["value"]])
```

Furthermore is it also possible to test "assert_called_one_with" with class objects?

Comment: Could you give a bit more context - why do you want to patch the thing you're supposed to be testing?

Comment: the method has some hardware dependencies which are not available on every system where the test should run.

Comment: I don't see why you need that `monkeypatch` and `mock_function` at all - it shall be sufficient to patch the function. Apart from that, it looks ok - maybe you are not patching the correct object. You have to show how and where `Engine` and `Service` are defined and imported for us to be able to understand the problem.

Comment: I just want that the method "test_function" of the Engine object not to be called in the test and its parameter to be checked. Is this already achieved by patching the method?

Comment: Yes, it is. As I wrote, your problem is probably that you don't patch the correct object (check [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6)).

Comment: ok, i didn't know that the patch method already ensures that the actual method is not called. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The patch method already ensures that the actual method is not called. The monkeypatch function ist not needed.